# Question about using Bayesian rule as a classification for continuous data set

Tags: bayesian, classification, copula, bayes-optimal-classifier

### Please note that my question is not about coding.

I am now learning Bayesian classification and I think I understand it in a discrete case. I have trouble understanding it for multivariate continuous data. My problem is in calculating the posterior.

### Example:

Assume that we have a data set with two classes. The first class (`D`) is the patient with a disease. The second class (`H`) is healthy patients. Assume that I have 25 patient. `15` of patients are suffer from the disease. Now we can estimate the posterior probability that the new patient is healthy (using Bayesian theorem) as:

$P(Glass= H | X=x)= \frac{\pi_{H} f_{h}(x)}{\pi_{H}f_{H}(x)+\pi_{D}f(_{D}(x)} \rightarrow {(1)} $.

Where x is a realisation of the random vector X (the patient), $f_{H}, f_{D}$ are the density of each class respectively.

Assume that I fit a copula model to this data. Assume further that I calculate the density of each class. Using copula, I will have this:

### This is just an example not a real data (for a simplification I assumed that `u` is the data.)

```
 set.seed(123)
u <- rCopula(15, frankCopula(3))
f_D <- dCopula(u, frankCopula(2.5))
f_D
 [1] 1.3446937 1.4909407 0.6999004 1.6392250 0.4032475 2.2401484 1.0616001 1.1444106 0.6963312 1.1229705
[11] 1.0431500 1.1350960 1.1060839 1.1336352 0.6921801
```

Now the density values of the first class is stored in `f_D`.

As we can see there are `15` values in `f_D`.

My question is (assume the prior of each class is `0.5`):

For the Bayesian theorem, how can I calculate the posterior in `(1)`?
Here, I have `15` values for `f_D`. Then, I should multiply them by `0.5` (the prior). However, I will not get a single value for the posterior! So, do I have to sum the values in `f_D` or product them?

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you don't use a direct probability model such as the binary logistic model.  And is the disease really all-or-nothing, i.e., is there not an underlying continuous or ordinal severity of disease measure?  I'm also unclear on the use of a copula here.  Copulas are typically used for multivariate outcomes while your outcome is univariate.